# Paramiko and Palo Alto Networks Firewall

Tags: python-3.x

I am a novice python user.

I am trying to connect to Palo Alto Networks Firewall to execute some commands and get output with Paramiko. The simple script I have just to try how it works is as below:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('1.1.1.1', port=22, username='admin', password='password')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show interface all')
output = stdout.readlines()
```

I found that script hangs after execution and hence tried the same in IDLE and saw the the shell hangs after I execute "output = stdout.readlines()". I also tried a few configuration commands as below and nothing happens on the firewall - e.g. it doesn't change firewall hostname in this instance:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('configure')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('set deviceconfig system hostname FW1')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('commit')
```

The same script if used on a Linux machine works very well (e.g. ls -l) and gives output in a second but somehow just doesn't work on Palo Alto Networks Firewall. I have seen several videos on youtube where people are successfully able to configure and manage Cisco routers with this script but somehow it's not working in my case. For information this is what happens when I login to firewall manually:

```
machine1:SSH user1$ ssh admin@1.1.1.1
Password:
Last login: Tue Dec 11 15:39:08 2018 from 1.1.1.2
This firewall is for authorized use only. Legal action will be taken against unauthorized users.
Number of failed attempts since last successful login: 0


admin@PA-VM>
```

I'll appreciate some thoughts and help on this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to work with PA's SSH CLI using Paramiko. But you can try the following:

```
ssh_client = SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(
    host,
    username=username,
    password=pwd
)
(
    ssh_stdin,
    ssh_stdout,
    ssh_stderr
) = ssh_client.exec_command(' ')
ssh_stdin.channel.send('show interface all')
ssh_stdin.channel.shutdown_write()
resp = ssh_stdout.read().decode('utf_8').split('\n')
print(resp)
ssh_client.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, @leonard! Is there any way to exclude "Number of failed attempts since last successful login" aside from adding logic in Python to process the response?

Answer (score 0):

here is my version with Methode: send_command()

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko.exceptions import NetMikoTimeoutException
from netmiko.exceptions import NetMikoAuthenticationException

cli_pattern = r"\)>\s"  # your cli pattern example: `admin@palofw(active-primary)>` -> `)>`

ssh_param = dict(
    device_type="paloalto_panos",
    host="ip addr",
    username="your user",
    password="your pw"
)
try:
    ssh = ConnectHandler(**ssh_param)

except ValueError as e:
    print(f"{self.host} error: {e}")

except NetMikoTimeoutException:
    print(
        f"{self.host} Cannot connect to device, "
        f"Please check if the network is communicating properly"
    )

except NetMikoAuthenticationException:
    logging.warning(f"{self.host} Logon failure, incorrect username or password")
    print(f"{self.host} Logon failure, incorrect username or password")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"{e=}")

print(ssh.send_command(command_string="show system info", expect_string=cli_pattern))
```